# pageBlockSection collapsible is not working

Tags: visualforce, css, pageblocksection

I have a visualforce page which has few pageblocksections. I need pageBlockSection to hide when the page loads with down arrow. I am using "collapsible=true" on that pageblocksection. but it is not working at all.

```
<apex:page controller="LoginEdit_AC"  docType="html-5.0">
<apex:sectionheader title="Edit" subtitle="{!records.Name}"/>
<apex:form id="theform"> 
    <apex:messages title="Errors Occured" styleClass="errorMsg" style="font-family:verdana,garamond,serif;" />
    <apex:pageBlock title="Blusynergy Edit" mode="edit" id="bluSynSettings">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="2">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!$ObjectType.Details__c.fields.Name.Updateable}">
                <apex:outputLabel value="User Name"/> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!bsyncDetails.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> ... ... ...
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="Controls how Accounts in Salesforce are exported to BluBilling, note that a Billing Contact is required for this.">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Export Accounts to BluBilling"/>
                <apex:selectList value="{!exportAccountString}" size="3">
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Manual" itemLabel="Manual" />
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="When Account and Contact are created" itemLabel="When Account and Contact are created" />
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="When Opportunity goes to Closed/Won" itemLabel="When Opportunity goes to Closed/Won" />
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Custom" itemLabel="Custom" />
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="conSettingList" action="{!exportAccountStringChanged}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="Determines which Salesforce contact will be responsible for billing when exported to the BluBilling system.">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Billing Contact Selection"/>
                <apex:selectList value="{!exportContactSelection}" size="3" id="conSettingList">
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="1st Contact created" itemLabel="1st Contact created" />
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Contact with BLUSYNERGY BILLING CONTACT Checked" itemLabel="Contact with BLUSYNERGY BILLING CONTACT Checked" />
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Contact associated with Opportunity"
                                       itemLabel="Contact associated with Opportunity"
                                       rendered="{!exportAccountString == 'When Opportunity goes to Closed/Won'}"/> 
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Additional Settings" columns="2" collapsible="true">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Custom Label 1"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!records.invoiceCustomLabel1__c}"/>  
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Custom Label 2"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!records.invoiceCustomLabel2__c}"/>  
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save"
                                action="{!save}"
                                reRender="theform"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" immediate="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Please check the screenshots.
[image]

1) How to add a box to two (Green highlighted box) pageBlockSectionItems ??

2) "collapsible=true" is not working at all. What to do? I need this section to be hidden on load and able to collapse by clicking "Additional options". As you can see, there is no arrow button showing in this section. No action at all when clicked on it.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the behaviour you get when you have `mode="edit"` on the `apex:pageBlock`.

You could see if one of the [other modes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlock.htm) suits your purpose. The full set is:

- detail
- maindetail
- edit
- inlineEdit

Comment: I really appreciate that. DropDown is working after removing mode tag. But it is collapsing after loading the page which we don't want. Also, how can I add a box to two pageBlockSectionitems?? Please advice.

Comment: Hi @AshSFcloud, Please only post questions when you have tried for some time (hours) yourself.

Comment: I tried different ways to get this done. Leave about the box thing. But I am not able to stop collapsing pageBlockSection on load. I followed "https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BKBKIA4" Link and other suggestions too. All other things are fine and your answer helped me for that.